# MikTex installation; paths

Tags: miktex, paths

I have installed MiKTex 2.9 64 bit for windows but it seems that I need to work on setting paths, because I get error messages like the following:

```
! I can't find file `graphicx'.
l.14 \input graphicx
! Undefined control sequence.
l.133 \includegraphics
                      [height=4truecm,width=8.5truecm]{D01F.eps}
! I can't find file `TXSdcol.tex'.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.31 \SetDoubleColumns
```

Anyone can tell me or direct me to the place showing how to setup MiKTeX properly. As it is I have to put everything in the same directory where my main file is; I have a macro file and if I want it called, it has to be exactly in the same directory where I have the main source file.

Comment: I was under the impression that MikTeX set its own paths. And although I believe that TeX does not care about Windows versus Linux line endings, I could be wrong... Are you mingling documents created on Linux with ones created on Windows? Finally, if nothing else works, consider using the portable version of MikTeX. It seems to solve some installation problems, and has the advantage that you can store a zipped copy of the whole thing, for later use if something goes wrong during an update.

Comment: Anyway it should be `\usepackage{graphicx}`, not `\input`. It's part of the basic installation, as far as I know.

Comment: Also, `TeXsis` is a set of `plain TeX` macro package (not LaTeX), and it not part of MiKTeX, you can download it from [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/texsis) on CTAN, and install it in a TeXMF-local root directory. As to the problem of graphicx, check if it is installed (via `MiKTeX Package Manager (Admin)`).

Comment: RobtAll, I am using files with .tex extension and I did not use Linux, all files are windows operating system. I will look into portable TeX as it looks promising

Comment: Kurt, this is a good question. I THOGHT I clicked "complete MikTeX, but when it came to installing I cannot guarantee it happened. What is an easy way to tell which one I actually installed?

Comment: @Bernard, I am processing everything with TeX, not Latex, better yet, I still have AMSTeX macros and other things. I will see whether \usepackage will work... And you may be right in that I need the plain TeX installed, which I did not know was not part of MiKTeX

Comment: plain TeX (the binary file) is of course installed, but TeXsis macro package  is not.

Comment: @Bernard \usepackage does not work with pdftex processing button I use. I notice that I have several places with \input files and there is no complaint, but with \input graphicx Graphicx is there and when I put files with that name in the current directory, it complains about some other file not being there...

Comment: @Rado: you should probably install (if it's not already there) `graphics-pln` and use `\input graphicx`.